# How to set size constraints when linear partitioning?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, partitioning

How can one add size constraints when solving the linear partition problem? I've implemented it verbatim from the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938809/dynamic-programming-linear-partitioning-please-help-grok?newreg=f1ec952412ce446b830d61fc1d891be7) using Skiena's algorithm. I'm wondering if there's a straight-forward way to limit the size of the resultant partitions.